# Can you always reduce 2 differential equations into a single differential equation with complex number substitution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers

Can you always reduce 2 differential equations into a single differential equation with complex number substitution?

e.g in the case of

$$\ddot{x}+\dot{y}+\dot{x}+x=0$$

$$\ddot{y}+\dot{x}+x+y=0$$

Here we use a substitution:

$$z=x+iy$$

so you can turn it into something similar as (I don't know how to solve this):

$$ \ddot{z} + i \dot{z} + ... =0$$

Where I don't know the exact representation of it in complex numbers

Comment: Not always. Not in your example.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Could you help me understand this?

Comment: In your example, you stopped writing exactly where it gets difficult; the fact is you're not going to be able to write more without either allowing functions for real and imaginary parts or for the complex conjugate, at which point you lose any real advantage. What you're doing is very similar to writing the differential equation in terms of vectors and matrices, which might be more useful for you.

Comment: Yes but I mean in general, it was not trying to solve it for the specific example

Answer (score 2):

The supposedly complex ODE should have the ansatz

$$
\ddot z + A \dot z + B z = 0
$$

with $z = x + i y,\ \ \{A,B\} \in \mathbb{C}$. Now calling $A = a_r+i a_i$ and $B = b_r + i b_i$ the following identity should be verified

$$
(\ddot x + i\ddot y)+(a_r+i a_i)(\dot x + i\dot y) + (b_r+i b_i)(x+i y) \equiv \ddot{x}+\dot{y}+\dot{x}+x+ i(\ddot{y}+\dot{x}+x+y) 
$$

so you can verify which values for $\{a_r,a_i,b_r,b_i\}\in\mathbb{R}$ if any, satisfy the condition.